# Transgressions resulting from trusting someone

Tags: intent-accident-purposely, trust-neemanut

For an action done based on information from others, what are the parameters for it to be considered intentional vs shogeg?

For example, let's say a man asked his wife if she's nidda and she told him no, but she was actually lying (for whatever reason). If he then has relations with her, is it considered shogeg (and thus requires a korban chatas)? Or do we say that he should have done at least some due diligence (e.g. ascertained when she went to the mikva) before taking her word - and if so what is the amount of due diligence needed, and how can it be quantified? [Again this has practical ramifications of requiring a korban or not]. Is believing her in good faith without having reason to doubt her enough for the action to be deemed unintentional, or are there cases when that's not the case?

As another example, what are the parameters involved in trusting a kashrut certifying agency before eating let's say something that can be potentially chametz on Pesach - if one believed the agency in good faith, would eating something that was in fact chametz be considered unintentional?

Comment: Unless you have reason to doubt their credibility, the general rule is עד אחד נאמן באיסורין.

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam writes ([Hil. Shegagos 2:8](https://www.chabad.org/torah-texts/1062903/Mishneh-Torah-Rambam/Sefer-Korbanot/Shegagot/Shegagot-Chapter-2#v8)):

> אִם בָּא עַל אִשְׁתּוֹ וַהֲרֵי הִיא נִדָּה חַיָּב חַטָּאת מִפְּנֵי שֶׁלֹּא שְׁאָלָהּ וְאַחַר כָּךְ יִבְעל
>
> If... one was intimate with his wife when she was in the niddah state, he is liable to bring a chatas, because he did not ask her before engaging in relations.

So the implication would seem to be that if he did ask, then he wouldn't be liable, because that would be considered enough due diligence. As shmosel noted in a comment, that's presumably because we consider one witness to be trustworthy enough for this purpose.